# Django app don't run locally, there is no "error" or somthing else...

Tags: python, html, django, heroku, web

I have Django 1.9 app that runs with python 3.5.1.
First when I run "manage.py runserver" I think it fail because I dont have  "psycopg2",he crushes because he couldn't find "psycopg2",
 I installed it with pip install,  and now there is no error, the "runserver" command works well and give me only that:

```
    $ /c/Python35/python.exe manage.py runserver 

C:\django-master\project\urls.py:12: RemovedInDjango110Warning: django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.
  url(r'^rank2/$', views.rank2, name='rank2'),)

C:\django-master\website\urls.py:21: RemovedInDjango110Warning: django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.
  url(r'^project/', include('project.urls')),
```

It looks like he is running but when I entered 127.0.0.1 there is nothing, its probably not really work, but I dont know how to debug it because there are no errors, how can I know where the problem is? (I know it could be lot of things but I don't have any direction...) 
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Django is per default running on port `8000` not port `80`. Either you go to `127.0.0.1:8000` or you start the server with `/c/Python35/python.exe manage.py runserver 80`

Comment: Hi,I know that from recent app I used, so I tried 127.0.0.1:8000 or with 80 and there was nothing... thanks....

Comment: Do you get the same result if you start it with `/c/Python35/python.exe manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`?